# Swift iOS Twitter API Fails

Tags: ios, json, twitter

I am trying to load some twitter feeds of a user on Swift iOS App. On twitter Documentation, I found the API is:

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2

which returns:

> {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}

Older Rest API did not require. Newer API requires authentication.

> Requires authentication?         Yes

How do I get that working? Any tutorials would be even sweeter!

**Before marking this question duplicate please bear in mind that I have done a good search and none of the answers answered my questions because a lot them point to older Rest APIs.**

Comment: I believe , all you need is the developer key

Comment: Have you got any solution, I have same problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807221/get-twitter-friends-list/54838712#54838712

Comment: Have you got any solution, I have same problem

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Twitter Fabric http://dev.twitter.com/fabric which is a free SDK (compatible with Swift) that provides easy authentication via either guest or user login. Sample app written in Swift at https://github.com/twitterdev/cannonball-ios

If you would prefer to use raw REST calls against the API, follow the OAuth details in our dev documentation https://dev.twitter.com/oauth

Answer (score 0):

In settings of your simulator go to accounts -> Twitter, and login there in actual twitter account. As you try to login, it doesn't know what user to use, so you need to specify it.